# Unable to Scrape Specific Website using Python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape this webpage using BS but to no avail. Could anyone help me? I am not sure what is wrong with this webpage or is there something wrong with my code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_url = "https://www.cea.gov.sg/Custom/CEA/PublicRegister/Page/PublicRegisterDetail.aspx?UserId=ae0cdf1d-a30c-4c8c-9f80-b2cec17b4bd9"

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = Soup(page_html, "html.parser")
nameList2 = page_soup.findAll("span")

print (nameList2.string[1])
```

Comment: At least for me this hangs already in the part where you open the url at `uReq(my_url)`, not sure why though. Using `requests`-library instead of urllib works.

The problem is not with bs4. Anyway, if that is solved, you still need to change `Soup` to `BeautifulSoup` and probably `nameList2.string[1]` to just `nameList2[1]`.

Comment: @teemu could you clarify what u mean by using requests library? How would that line of code look like instead? Yes i have changed soup to beautifulsoup

Comment: What I mean is a third-party library that is in many ways much better than urllib, but that would mean more than just changing one line. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ if you are interested.

Comment: I see.. And that is the only way to do it?

Comment: Most probably not, I'm just saying that it _works_ with requests. It _should_ work the way you have it now, but for some reason that I don't know it does not. Probably something to do with the server you are fetching the data from.

Comment: Hi teemu, thanks for the reply.. And honestly i am also scratching my head as to why it doesnt work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this. I didn't find anything problematic out there.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.cea.gov.sg/Custom/CEA/PublicRegister/Page/PublicRegisterDetail.aspx?UserId=ae0cdf1d-a30c-4c8c-9f80-b2cec17b4bd9")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
for item in soup.select(".form-wrap"):
    Name = item.select_one("#FtPublicRegisterDetail_LblName").get_text()
    Agent_Name = item.select_one("#FtPublicRegisterDetail_LblEstAgentName").get_text()
    print(Name, Agent_Name)
```

The result:

```
A R N MADANAGOPALAN (MADAN) PROPNEX REALTY PTE LTD
```

And using only "span" if you prefer:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.cea.gov.sg/Custom/CEA/PublicRegister/Page/PublicRegisterDetail.aspx?UserId=ae0cdf1d-a30c-4c8c-9f80-b2cec17b4bd9")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")

doc_list = soup.select("span")

for item in range(len(doc_list)):
    names = soup.select("span")[item].text
    print(names)
```

Results:

```
A R N MADANAGOPALAN (MADAN)
R016176H
01 Jan 2013 to 31 Dec 2017
NA
NA
NA
PROPNEX REALTY PTE LTD
```

Comment: hi Shahin, many thanks. Managed to get it after using "import requests", but not for urllib...